# How to allow a certain app on a certain standard user account but not on another standard user account?

Tags: windows-10, standard-user

Let's say I have two standard user accounts. I want to allow a program on one of the standard user account, but not on the other standard user account. Is this possible to accomplish? Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to have administrator permissions for doing this.

You may in Explorer right-click the program's `.exe` file and select "Properties".

In the Security tab, you will see the accounts that are authorized to access
the file, where you may remove or add user accounts. Click "Edit" to modify.

Leave alone standard accounts such as "SYSTEM" or "Administrators".
Remove other broadly general accounts such as "Users" or "Everyone",
then add your account.

For more information see the article
[How to Change Permissions of File, Folder, Drive, or Registry Key for Users and Groups in Windows 10](https://www.tenforums.com/tutorials/88436-change-permissions-objects-users-groups-windows-10-a.html).